# Finding all possible addition and combination given a fixed number in c ( given a sum, find the possible addition and permutation of it.)

Tags: c++

I'm looking for all the possible combination of number and the permutation of them in a fixed size of array. For example, I have the total number of 5 the desired output will be

5 0 0 0

0 5 0 0

0 0 5 0

0 0 0 5

4 1 0 0

1 4 0 0

1 0 4 0

1 0 0 4

0 1 4 0

and so on... is this possible ?

Comment: you mean the total always has to be 5?

Comment: How about `6 -1 0 0`?

Comment: Should 3 number combinations, like `2 2 1 0`, be acounted too?

Comment: All things are possible. How much time do you have?

Comment: If you just want to count the number of combinations, you can do a DP where your DP array is defined as `dp[i][j] = number of ways to sum to j using i numbers`. If you want to print all the combinations, use a recursive DFS as shown in pfctgeorge's answer.

Comment: These are called [integer compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) which is related to integer partitions, only order matters.

Comment: @bcperth not really, 5 is just an example

Comment: @GMachado yea, it should

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion:

```
void find(int remain, int depth, vector<int> v) {
    if (depth == 4) {
        if (remain == 0){
            for (int i = 0 ;i < 4; i++) {
                cout << v[i];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= remain; i++) {
        v.push_back(i);
        find(remain-i, depth+1, v);
        v.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could pass the vector by reference so you don't copy the whole thing every time you call the function.

Comment: Yeah, good advice. But since I'm not very familiar with c++, I just use a brute solution to give some hint.

Comment: This solution is inefficient. :O

Comment: Also, there is only one possibility for the last number, so you don't need to loop over that.